# Espresso framework always convert body to string?

Tags: ruby, web-frameworks

I need an action to return an `Array`(it will be later processed by a middleware).

However, this always convert returned value to string:

```
def logs
  # logic here
  [1, 2, 3]
end
```

How to tell Espresso to return it as is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question.

And there is a good answer :)

Use `response.body` setter:

```
def logs
  # logic here
  response.body = [1, 2, 3]
end
```